# Refresh the page after product remove from cart Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am facing this issue in woocommerce. When product us removed from the cart, then update cart button disabled. And after the refresh page is working fine.

I am trying this hook:

```
woocommerce_cart_item_removed
```

But its not working return nothing.

Comment: Please provide an example of it.So, i can help you.

Comment: Hi WisdmLabs, When cart page contains more then one product and when user goes to remove one product from the cart, Then user want to increase another product qty. but user can't update the cart. Because update cart button is disable. That's the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions of Woocommerce there is a JavaScript callback trigger available as described in [this commit](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/commit/f8f065bad99243614d2af141d635a00c47248161):

```
/**
 * Update the .cart_totals div with a string of html.
 *
 * @param {String} html_str The HTML string with which to replace the div.
 */
var update_cart_totals_div = function( html_str ) {
    $( '.cart_totals' ).replaceWith( html_str );
    $( document.body ).trigger( 'updated_cart_totals' );
};
```

So you can add a piece of Javascript to run when this trigger is fired and enable the button or simply refresh the page. For example:

```
$('body').on('updated_cart_totals',function() {
    $( '.shop_table.cart' ).closest( 'form' ).find( 'input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', false ); // this will enable the button.
    //location.reload(); // uncomment this line to refresh the page.
});
```

Comment: Thanks leendertvb for your answer. Try this in my next site :)