# Refresh the WooCommerce cart page when a product is deleted

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using this question [Refresh the page after product remove from cart Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560342/refresh-the-page-after-product-remove-from-cart-woocommerce) I added the below code to the head of my website to refresh the WooCommerce cart page when a product is deleted but it does not work. I need the page to refresh as I have a custom product image and it's merging into the product below when deleted unless the cart page is refreshed.

```html
<script>
jQuery('body').on('updated_cart_totals',function() {
    jQuery( '.shop_table.cart' ).closest( 'form' ).find( 'input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', false ); // this will enable the button.
    //location.reload(); // uncomment this line to refresh the page.
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting for anyone else who searches for this. Works for me if you remove the // at the start of the location.reload() line as per the instructions. Placed in footer.